# Why can I not get local files to parse using BeautifulSoup4 in Jupyterlab

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, jupyter-lab

I'm following a web tutorial trying to use BeautifulSoup4 to extract data from a html file (stored on my local PC) in Jupyterlab as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open ('simple.html') as html_file:
    simple = BeautifulSoup('html_file','lxml')

print(simple.prettify())
```

I'm getting the following output irrespective of what is in the html file instead of the expected html

```
<html>
 <body>
  <p>
   html_file
  </p>
 </body>
</html>
```

I've also tried it using the html parser html.parser and I simply get `html_file` as the output.
I know it can find the file because when I run the code after removing it from the directory I get a FileNotFoundError.

It works perfectly well when I run python interactively from the same directory. I'm able to run other BeautifulSoup to parse web pages.

I'm using Fedora 32 linux with Python3, Jupyterlab, BeautifulSoup4,requests, lxml installed in a virtual environment using pipenv.

Any help to get to the bottom of the problem is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in this line:

```
simple = BeautifulSoup('html_file','lxml')
```

In particular, you're telling BeautifulSoup to parse the literal string `'html_file'` instead of the contents of the variable `html_file`.

Changing it to:

```
simple = BeautifulSoup(html_file,'lxml')
```

(note the lack of quotes surrounding `html_file`) should give the desired result.